# Send email from server without SMTP enabled

Tags: forms, email, c#-4.0, smtp, sendmail

I have written a couple of web sites that contain a "contact us" form.

However, our host recently switched SMTP off. Their excuse is "security issues".

The solution they offer is that they implemented rules whereby all mail generated from the platforms must be sent using the sendmail/phpmail functions and pass through a mail relay which checks the mails and their content and ensures malicious content and activity is completely blocked and they recommend I use "A virtual or dedicated solution".

I have no idea what it is they want me to do to get emailing working again and this is quite urgent as many clients are not getting their emails.
Is there an easy way to go around this in order to get emailing working again?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It generally means that you will have to specify the new mail server they are providing instead of localhost in your code. Further, earlier, you were able to send the mail without authenticating but now on, you must have an account and you must authenticate before you send the mail. (I am not sure though, may be they allow relay to their own servers and you might not need authentication).

Go to the control panel of your hosting account and check for the mail panel. Check out the new smtp server name there and code your site to use this smtp server with credentials. This will let you send mail again.

Comment: Oh sounds promising. So I don't have to reimplement the whole form, I just need to give it other parameters in the web.config?
I'll try to find the smtp server settings and I'll let you know how that went. Thanks!

Comment: yes, it is just the mail server which has changed, nothing else.

Comment: Ok so I got one site working but the other site's server only offers pop and imap servers.
What do I do now?
Can I use some external smtp that is public and free like gmail or something? Can I use the pop or imap server instead?

Comment: You can do either of them. It is also possible to use imap server for sending mail. At the same time, you can also use third party mail servers which are commercially available. If you are not sure about the performance of your mail server, I would recommend to use any third party dedicated mail server.

Comment: So I'll try doing this in the web.config:
<network host="some pop server" userName="x" password="y" />

Comment: It is not necessary to put these values in web.config file. It is only required if any of your httpmodule is using these values. If it is the case, you are in hard luck unless that module is capable of completely understanding it.

Comment: It all worked fine. I used SMTP server for both and it all worked fine as soon as I update the web.config